# infinite loop in search function for PHP array

Tags: php, loops, search

as exercise I need to create a search function. in this function, input is a value and output is number of times that the value is repeated in array. but an error shows:

**"Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 178257920) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ... on line 51"**

PHP code is:

```
        //here is first part of search function.
    class searching extends JsonHelper {
        public $s = 0;
        public function search($index) {
            $temp = $this->myarray;
            $s = $this->s;
            foreach ($temp as $value) {
                if(!is_array($value)) {
                    if ($value == $index) {
                        echo "i found something";
                        $s += 1;
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->searchB($value, $index , $temp);
                }
            }
        }
        //secend part of search for arrays that are deeper
        function searchB($A, $B, $C) {
            $s = $this->s;foreach ($A as $AA){
                if (!is_array($AA)) {
                    if ($AA == $B) {
                        echo "i found something";
                        $s += 1;
                    } else {
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->searchB($A, $B, $C); //line 51 is here
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    $object = new searching("jsonProject.json");
    echo $object->search("pro8");
    echo $object->s;
    $object->s = 0;
```

json file that show there is 4 "pro8"

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Client": "client 1",
        "Project": "project 1",
        "StartDate": "2018\/11\/02 16:57:35",
        "CompletedDate": "",
        "projectUrl": "project-1",
        "pro": {
            "pro2": "pro8",
            "pro4": "pro8",
            "pro6":
            {
                "pro7": "pro8",
                "pro9": "pro8"
            }

        }
    }
]
```

how to solve this infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinate loop comes from this statement:

```
$this->searchB($A, $B, $C); //line 51 is here
```

You are pointing to the same variable $A in stead of $AA I suppose you want this:

```
$this->searchB($AA, $B, $C); //line 51 is here
```

Oner other thing

```
$s += 1;
```

will not change

```
$this->s
```

Better just use

```
$this->s += 1;
```

Or even better

```
$this->s++;
```